# jQuery on click using .before()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have this method, that does some ajax and with the result makes a new div before a div and then inserts the ajax response in it. The problem i have is while using on('click') my second click appends a new div before the previously created div(what i want) but also creates another div after(not what i want) that is exactly the same.

AJAX/jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ajaxcommentbutton1', function() {
var currentDiv, pageValue, newPage, newPageid;
currentDiv = $(this).attr('group');
pageValue = parseFloat($(this).attr('data'));
newPage = pageValue + 1;
newPageid =  '.' + newPage;

$.ajax({url:"comments.php",
       type:'POST',              
   dataType:'text',
       data: {id: currentDiv,
              page: newPage},
    success:function(result){
        $('div[data="' + currentDiv + '"] .commentsContainer > div').before("<div class='" + newPage + "'>&nbsp</div>");
        $('div[data="' + currentDiv + '"] ' + newPageid).html(result);
        $('button[group="' + currentDiv + '"]').attr('data', newPage);
        $('button[group="' + currentDiv + '"]').off();
   }});
});
```

HTML Result of first click:

```
<div class='commentsContaier'>
   <div class="2">stuff in here</div>
   <div class="1">stuff in here</div>
</div>
```

HTML Result of second click (BAD ONE):

```
<div class='commentsContaier'>
   <div class="3">stuff in here</div>
   <div class="2">stuff in here</div>
   <div class="3">stuff in here</div>
   <div class="1">stuff in here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `$('div[data="' + currentDiv + '"] .commentsContainer > div')` matches every `<div>` under your container, and [`.before()`](https://api.jquery.com/before/) will add your AJAX content into every matched `<div>`, duplicating your AJAX content.

i.e. in the second click, the new element is inserted into both `<div class="1">stuff in here</div>` and `<div class="2">stuff in here</div>`

Try replace it with `$('div[data="' + currentDiv + '"] .commentsContainer > div:first-child')` to match only the first child of all the `<div>`s, with the [`:first-child`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector